# Uncaught Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

I am using highcharts.js lib in my project,I am getting the error as Uncaught Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16.

I know that the error comes due to lib is loaded twice,but I need help that how I avoid this situation.

Basically I am using ajax request for getting the html response from .jsp file.

Scenario:
1.I have tree from d3.js where I am clicking on the tree node at that time I am sending the ajax request and getting whole page of html response,in that I have included the highchars.js lib

2.Right now I am on my product dashboard page,and right now I am clicking on back button which having ajax request,and after that again I am clicking on tree node which gives me my product dashboard page in this situation I am getting error as 
Uncaught Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16.

can anybody help me to overcome this situation.

Thanks,
Nandu.

Comment: Make sure you are not including highcharts.js in your layout file. If you are already including it in the layout then you don't need to include it in the html response.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens the second time Highcharts or Highstock is loaded in the same page.
It means you should not include/load highchart.js file again.
I have simple solution over this, and this is working fine for me.

while sending ajax request pass some variable like 'call'

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.YourUrlHere.php?key=234&call=ajax", 
    success: function(result){
    $('body').html(result);
    }
   });
```

And while you include/load highchart.js files check if this variable is set or not, if it is set then don't include/load this files again.
(belove example is for PHP)

```html
<?php if(empty($_GET['call'])){ ?>
<script src="assets/Highcharts/code/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/Highcharts/code/modules/exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php } ?>
```